# windows 8 task manager virtualization option

Tags: c++, windows, virtual-machine, vmware, parallels

I am trying to find a way to programatically detect that my program runs on a virtual machine, as far as I know there is no common way for parallels to do that.

Windows 8 task manager performance tab displays a "Virtaulization" option, what does it mean? When i run windows 8 in a virtual machine it changes to virtual processors and virtual machine: yes, so some how windows 8 detects that it is running inside a virtual machine, how does windows 8 detect that it is running in a virtual machine? Is it possible to get this information programatically? I tried both on parallels and vm ware and both works fine.

Comment: On my real Windows 8, Task Manager shows "Virtualization: Enabled" as well. I believe it indicates that the processor supports Virtualization, not that the OS runs in a VM.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at this interesting article *`Red Pill... or how to detect VMM using (almost) one CPU instruction`* by *`Joanna Rutkowska`* which used to be [here](http://invisiblethings.org/papers/redpill.html) but is now dead and can only be viewed with the [waybackmachine here](http://web.archive.org/web/20110929075510/http://invisiblethings.org/papers/redpill.html) and *`Virtualization: Red Pill or Blue?`* by *`Steven McElwee`* which also used to be [here](http://www.redlightsecurity.com/2008/04/virtualization-red-pill-or-blue.html) but can now only be viewed [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20100725003848/http://www.redlightsecurity.com/2008/04/virtualization-red-pill-or-blue.html).

Heres the code:

```
int swallow_redpill()
{
    unsigned char m[2+4], rpill[] = "\x0f\x01\x0d\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc3";
    *((unsigned*)&rpill[3]) = (unsigned)m;
    ((void(*)())&rpill)();
    return (m[5]>0xd0) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

It should return 1 if running in a virtual machine and 0 if not.

---

Edit: It may return false-positives on modern cpus and its [apparently better to combine](http://charette.no-ip.com:81/programming/2009-12-30_Virtualization/) a couple of [tests](http://www.offensivecomputing.net/files/active/0/nopill.cpp) together to make sure the result is real.

Answer (score 1):

On VMware you could check for the CD drive vendor- should be "VMware" or "VMware, Inc." or something like this.

I don't know about VMware workstation but on ESXi your MAC address generally starts with "00:50:56". You could make use of this, too.

Have a look at [virt-what](http://people.redhat.com/~rjones/virt-what/). Maybe you can port it to Windows.

And maybe [How to detect install is running on a VM?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/55bbcf5d-9396-4904-bc03-b1c2d4647657/how-to-detect-install-is-running-on-a-vm) can help you.